# Find the current top view controller and push view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar, pushviewcontroller

I have a UICollectionView like this:

[image]

On each cell, I add a button. When I click that button, it will push to an other view controller. It works fine. But when I try to click 2 button at the same time(eg: Cell 1 and Cell 7). It call "push" twice. And I receive warning:

> nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar. 
>   Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar
>   subview tree might get corrupted.

Here is my code:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
+ (AppDelegate *)shareInstance{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

- (UIViewController *)currentVisibleController{
    id rootController = self.window.rootViewController;

    if ([rootController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)rootController;
        return navigationController.topViewController;
    }

    if ([rootController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {

        UITabBarController *tabbarController = (UITabBarController *)rootController;
        id topViewController = [tabbarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:tabbarController.selectedIndex];
        if ([topViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            UINavigationController *navi = (UINavigationController *)topViewController;
            return navi.topViewController;
        }

        return topViewController;
    }
    return self.window.rootViewController;
}
```

When I press on a cell:

**CustomCell.m**

```
- (IBAction)pressOnCell:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([SecondViewController class]) bundle:nil];
    [[AppDelegate shareInstance].currentVisibleController.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set animated option in **pushViewController** to NO. Or you can disable user interaction on collection view on **viewWillDisAppear** and then enable it in **viewWillAppear**. Or you can call **pressOnCell** in **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** and set **allowsMultipleSelection** property of collection view to NO.